# Is there a JSR-330 equivalent of Spring's @Bean or Guice's @Provides annotation?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, jsr330

I tried using `@Named` annotation on methods that create a bean, but that doesn't seem to work. Couldn't find any question here or a blog that confirms this. Reading the description at jcp.org, I don't see any relationship b/w beans and dependency injection introduced by JSR-330 either: https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=330

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, JSR-330 does not have the equivalent of Spring's `@Bean` or Guice's `@Provides` annotations.

There are only 5 annotations in JSR-330, and they are equivalent to the following Spring<sup>1</sup> / Guice<sup>2</sup> annotations:

```
JSR-330      Spring                Guice
----------   -------------------   ------------------
@Inject      @Autowired            @Inject
@Named       @Component            @Named
@Qualifier   @Qualifier            @BindingAnnotation
@Scope       @Scope                @ScopeAnnotation
@Singleton   @Scope("singleton")   @Singleton
-            @Scope("prototype")   -
```

<sup>*1) From [Using JSR 330 Standard Annotations](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.2.7.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-standard-annotations) and [Using JSR 330 Standard Annotations](http://springtechnotes.blogspot.com/2015/12/using-jsr-330-standard-annotations.html)*</sup>
<sup>*2) From [JSR-330 Integration](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/JSR330#jsr-330-integration)*</sup>

They do not match up exactly, so read the articles listed in the footnotes for full detail.

Comment: While it unfortunately does not cover Guice, more information about the similarities and differences between CDI and Spring (and how to jump between them) can be found at; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67132894/what-is-springboot-alternative-to-javaee-cdi/67154490#67154490.